# Chapter not being included

Tags: include

Hello I am trying to write my thesis to include different chapters my master tex document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=4.0cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} 
\renewcommand\bibname{References}

\graphicspath{ {./Thesis pictures/} }

\includeonly{Chapter3_content1}

\begin{document}
\title{
\huge{\textbf{Luminescent properties of semiconductor materials}}\\[1.2cm]
\Large{A thesis submitted to the University of Manchester \\ for the degree of Doctor     of Philosophy in the Facultly of Engineering and Physical Science} \\[1cm]
\Large{2015} \\
\Large{Rachel Southern-Holland} } 
\author{} 
\date{}
\maketitle

\newpage

\include{F:/Rachel_thesis/Chapters/Chapter3_content1}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliography{PhD_Library}
\end{document}
```

and the tex file Chapter3_content1 looks like this

```
\chapter

this is my methods chapter
```

However when I compile the master document I only get the title page and not the content from the Chapter3_content1 file.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot

Comment: If I were to guess: maybe because you have the full path in `\include`, but only the filename in `\includeonly`.

Comment: You *can't* have a full path in the argument to `\include`; for security reasons, TeX will refuse to write the `.aux` file pertaining to such an `\include`d file.

Answer (score 1):

The following works. Note that what you put in your `\includeonly` and `\include` should
coincide. I've also trimmed the code to make it more like a MWE.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Chapter3_content1}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{My third chapter}
The content of the third chapter is here.

Also, this is my methods chapter.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Chapter4_content1}
\chapter{My fourth chapter}
\end{filecontents}
\includeonly{Chapter3_content1}
\begin{document}
\title{Luminescent properties of semiconductor materials}
\author{Rachel Southern-Holland}
\maketitle
\include{Chapter3_content1}
\include{Chapter4_content1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry still not working just get chapter headings but not the content from chapter3_content1 file.

Comment: Also forgive my ignorance, what is a MWE?

Comment: MWE stands for Minimal Working Example, i.e., a piece of code that can be cut and pasted and compiled (Working) and that does not contain irrelevant things (Minimal).

Comment: In the example the files only contain the chapter headings and no text. If you want text, you have to add it! I have added some in my edit.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty confused now. My original tex file chapter3_content1 had text in it saying "this is my methods chapter" and that's gone now. What did I/you do?

Comment: Please have a look at the edit of the code. Note also that the idea here is not to reproduce the content of your chapter but to show how to get the `\includeonly` command to work as expected.

Comment: Denis has used `filecontents` package to put in a single document different files. If you have different files you should remove the `filecontents` environments.

Comment: @Astrinus Thanks for the clarifying comment!